# Loop predefined sequence through cells in excel

Tags: list, excel, sequence, cycle, vba

Have been searching for a few hours now I'm stuck. Not really sure what I'm searching for but guessing some VBA.

What I want to do in excel is this:

Have a predefined list i.e. [a,a#,b,c,c#...g#]

Now when somebody enters value 'A' into cell A20 then A19 will be the next on the list 'A#', A18 will be 'B', A17 will be 'C' etc.

If the value C is entered into cell A20 then A19 would be 'C#' and so on...

Once the list reaches G# it shall repeat from A again. This would repeat until cell A2 is reached.

Even a point in the right direction would be great as I don't really know what to search for. Have tried 'arrays' 'loop' 'cycle' without much luck.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You would do better learning the basics of VBA than searching for odd terms.  Search for "Excel VBA Tutorial".  There are many to choose from so try a few then complete the one that matches your learning style.  I prefer books.  I visited a good library; reviewed their Excel VBA Primers and then the borrowed what I thought were the best to try at home.  Finally I bought the best as a permenent reference book.

Your questions is very unclear but I think you need a `For Each` loop within a `Do` loop.  You will find an introduction to loops near the start of any tutorial or primer. Try to develop this:

```
Sub demo()

  Dim CellId As Variant
  Dim LoopCount As Long

  ' #### Replace Tidy with the name of a worksheet in your workbook.
  With Worksheets("Tidy")

    Do While True
      For Each CellId In Array("A20", "A19", "A18", "A17")

        Debug.Print CellId & "=" & .Range(CellId).Value

        If LoopCount >= 3 Then
          Exit Do
        End If

      Next
      LoopCount = LoopCount + 1

    Loop

  End With

End Sub
```

Comment: You're probably right. I should start learning it. It's just finding the time and I have usually get by 'winging it' as I don't use too often.

Appologies about the rubbish explanation I thought it was clear.

I'll try and rephrase:

In Cell A20 the user can choose one of the following values from a dropdown menu. A, A#, B, C, C#, D, D#, E, F, F#, G, G#.

Every subsequent cell above A20 (up until A2) will show the next letter in sequence. So if A is selected the sequence will start there. If D is selected, the cell above will be D# and so on. G# is the end of the sequence and it will repeat.

Comment: But yes. I think I will try and learn the basics so I can make a better stab at it first time. Otherwise people are just basically writing it for me which is not very efficient, not to mention rude. Thanks for the help though.